# Show that $\sum_{j=M}^{\infty}\left(\frac{M}{j}\right)^{a+n} \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, summation

Assume this is to be solved under timed conditions.

> Show that
>   $\sum_{j=M}^{\infty}\left(\frac{M}{j}\right)^{a+n}
>  \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, where $M\geq 1$ is an integer and
>   $a > 1$ is fixed (not necessarily an integer).

I do have a solution available to me, but I'm not a fan of it - essentially, it breaks apart the summation into $1 + \sum_{j=M+1}^{\infty}(M/j)^{a+n}$ and then does some fancy inequality work to show that the resulting summation starting at $j = M + 1$ is less than or equal to some constant not dependent on $n$ times $\left(\dfrac{M}{M+1}\right)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, hence we get $1^{-1} = 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Long story short, I wouldn't have thought about doing this (particularly the breaking of the summation into two parts).

Is there a better, more brute-force method of approaching this that wouldn't involve messing around with inequalities? Note that this was an intermediate step for a question from a grad-level statistics qualifying exam, covering material at the level of Casella and Berger's text.

Comment: What's the purpose of the $-1$ power?

Comment: @zhw. I suppose it's not necessary. If you would prefer that I remove it, I can do that.

Comment: I would always recommend removing unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @zhw. The power has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Breaking it into two parts is very natural, since the first term in the sum is $1.$ I'm not sure why we have $a+n.$ I would just write the power as $p$ and let $p\to \infty.$ You are then trying to show

$$\sum_{j=M+1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{M}{j}\right)^p \to 0$$

as $p\to \infty.$ I can see either a comparison to an integral, or a dominated convergence theorem approach to this.